# I lost apps account on twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth

I lost my apps account on Twitter, with which I registered an application in apps.twitter.com for oauth. I don'y know the email. But my site uses this application to authorize users. If I create a new app, then users will lose authorization on my site. Twitter don't want to help me in the recovery of the account and the application. What to do?

I know twitter_id and twitter_secret sure.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I can create new app. But new app == new account in my site? Or possible connect old account on my site and new app?

Comment: Yes, a get an user id from Twitter. Hmm, thnx. I thought that if I lose the application, I can'tt connect my users and new application, so that the users id are same.

Comment: If you have the consumer key and secret for the app and are able to prove that it belongs to an account belonging to you or your company, you can raise a ticket via https://help.twitter.com/forms/platform - otherwise there's no way to demonstrate it's really your app, which makes things difficult.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly a coding question, but relates to administering Twitter accounts.

Comment: Jonas, thank you! Your answer was very useful.